# NSSearchField and tableview for dynamic search

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nssearchfield

I'm trying to port my IOS App on OSX.

In my IOS App I have a UISearchBar. When the user is typing a character I send HTTP requests to extract data from a server based on user input and I refresh the content of the tableview.
Next the user can select in the tableview the right row he was looking for.

I want to have the same mechanism on OSX, something similar to the search text field in the Map App in Maverick.

In my OSX App I have a NSSearchField and when the user is typing I can send the HTTP request and extract the data from my server but how can I associate a "tableview" to the NSSearchField to display the results?

I have the NSSearchField in the NSToolbar of my window and like Map App I would like to display search result in a list below.

Comment: There's a discussion of creating a custom pseudo-menu like you're referring to in the [WWDC 2010 Session 145 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/#145-video). It's called "Key Event Handling in Cocoa Applications" but as the video itself notes, that's a bit of an incomplete title. Check it out.

Comment: Oh, and there's sample code that goes with that video: [CustomMenus](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CustomMenus/Introduction/Intro.html).